# How do I set up cljsbuild to move non-compiled files into a specific folder?

Tags: build, clojurescript, cljsbuild

My Clojurescript project is starts with three files -- an index.html, a css file, the hand-written .cljs code.

When cljsbuild builds the .cljs file into a .js file, it puts it in an arbitrary location. I'd like to also move the index.html and css files there too.

The reason I want this is so I can have multiple profiles, and easily load both. I have a `dev` profile where the javascript isn't optimized, and a `release` profile that does optimize javascript. But switching between them is annoying -- I have to somehow take the single existing index.html file and change the javascript file it's pointing at. (If I have two `index.html` files, each pointing to a different javascript file, making a change to one html file means duplicating the change in the other)

I'd rather have two builds:

`dev` build builds to `project/dev`.

`release` build builds to `project/release`.

Both builds would have `index.html`, `style.css`, and `compiled.js` files. Is there any way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

For doing that I think you are going to need additional tooling to your project.

Frontend tooling is a tough world with lots of alternatives and workflows each with their tradeoffs.

The simplest way would be having a makefile and invoke it when you want HTML and CSS copied/compiled. That should get you started but it is hard to get working on Windows.

For a established cross platform solution I'd look into integrating grunt to the workflow. With grunt you can easily have a file watcher copy/compile your HTML and CSS to your folders and even have the files minified/linted. The tradeoff is a steeper learning curve and initial setup of the project.

There are lots of options but not any cljs specific tooling that I know of.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This situation is what is, but is suboptimal -- with `lein cljsbuild auto`, I don't have to stop to run a build; it's a shame I have to add extra tooling or have an entirely different workflow for release builds.

Comment: What you would have to do is have two tools watching (cljsbuild looking at .cljs files and (make/grunt/...) looking at html/css/less/js files). If you just want something to be executed when cljsbuild recompiles, then you can use `:notify-command` for that (but that wont make cljsbuild file-watch html and css files, it may be enough, tough). Here is a link to the example conf: https://github.com/emezeske/lein-cljsbuild/blob/70a0d85782182a09c1116049b09a5f8ca5a7bd30/sample.project.clj#L73-L78